# AngularJS: Multiple directives [ngView, ngView] asking for transclusion on: <!-- ngView: -->

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The version we use for AngularJS is 1.2.28. We also use RequireJS and a library called ocLazyLoad (0.4.0) for lazy loading of Angular stuff.

The problem is very rare and there is no way to reproduce it in consistent manner.

Basically, the user just opens the application, we show some loading screens and when everything is ready (files are loaded and $viewContentLoaded is fired), we show the application itself.

The ugly part is that everything works just fine, but in some rare cases it just crashes saying: 
`Multiple directives [ngView, ngView] asking for transclusion on: <!-- ngView:  -->`
If the user reloads the page everything is OK.

We have only one ng-view added to a div.

Currently, I've tried different configs on ocLazyLoad like adding

```
loadedModules: ['module']
```

Also placing the ng-view in different DOM element.

None of them are working.

So any ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: Do you have any directives providing HTML views?

Comment: Hello, we have several ng-include directives inside partials that are loaded based on url.